# Node js net tcp client

Tags: node.js, tcpclient

Following is a net tcp client code

```
var net = require('net');
var client = new net.Socket();
client.connect(1337, '127.0.0.1', function() {
   console.log('Connected');
   client.write('Hello server');
});

client.on('data', function(data) {
   console.log('Received: ' + data);
   client.destroy(); // kill client after server's response
});

client.on('close', function() {
   console.log('Connection closed');
});
```

client.write('Hello server') is written inside the client.connect scope.
Is there a way to use it outside the client.connect scope.

I tried the following code but failed to send anything to server. However the return value of client.write returned true.

```
var net = require('net');
var client = new net.Socket();
client.connect(1337, '127.0.0.1', function() {
   console.log('Connected');
});

client.write('Hello server');  //Did not work
```

Comment: `client.write` will execute BEFORE `client.connect` is <ahem> connected. That's why it must go in the callback.

Comment: You cannot *write* before you *connect*. The second example you added doesn't work because it calls *write* before connection is made since *client.connect* is asyncronous. So all you need to do is to check you are connected before you *write*.